# Hide specific points in series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to toggle specific points in a series in Highcharts based on a value in the data object.  Is this possible at all?  I can't see anything in the [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data) that says a point within a series can be toggled.

I know I can remove points specifically, but I would much rather hide them, as the user will want to show/hide rather frequently, and I don't want to rebuild the whole series every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Point.update` and set the marker radius to 0.

```
selectedPoint.update({marker: { radius: 0 }});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is to use the point.remove and series.addpoint calls. I don't think that highcharts has a concept of hidden points.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid dropping points from the series if I can help it.  I don't want to go back to the server every time a series needs redrawn, and caching data client side a 2nd time just seems wasteful